# How to get All Numbers from an Addition?

Tags: math

## Is it Possible to Solve this

Suppose I only have 5 numbers (for example): 8, 12, 37, 202, and 7

and the only things I know are that:

1. The result is 266.
2. I have used 5 digits.

**Is it possible to figure out all those 5 numbers, by using a mathematical procedure?**

Comment: I want to mathematically solve this problem. :(

Comment: There's not one solution. `8+12+37+201+8` would work too.  So would `8+12+37+203+6`.  So would ...

Comment: A simple counterexample is enough to answer negatively: $12+34=46=32+14$.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "I have used 5 digits here"? The left side of your question has 6 digits (0,1,2,3,7,8) and the right side adds another (6). What do you mean by "number"? Do you want a count of the ways to do the addition or a list of all the ways? Does rearranging the order of the numbers count as a new way? And so on. Please clarify.

Comment: I interpret this question to mean: you have the multiset S = {8, 1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 0, 2, 7} and want to combine these digits by either concatenation (eg, 8 and 7 make 87, 2 and 3 make 23) or addition (eg, 87+23 = 110) to get 266. I assume you're giving 8+12+37+202+7 as one of several solutions. If that is your question, try asking on math.SE

Comment: Thanks all..... I think there's a solution..... Just need an expert for help...

Comment: Do you claim that all numbers are different and non-negative? Then sometimes it is possible.

Comment: @StanislavKralin yes...All number is different and non-negetaive..But HOw?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, and there are at least a few ways to look at it. The short answer is no, you can't figure out the five numbers knowing only their sum. But there is more to say about it. Take a look at "underdetermined system of equations" and "partitions of integers" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Ok.. I'm researching on it.

Comment: If you need help with understanding some of the stuff you find, my advice is to post questions to math.stackexchange.com about it. Good luck and have fun, it's a good topic.

Answer (score -1):

If you only know that there are 5 numbers that add up to 266, you will not be able to calculate/figure out what those 5 individual numbers are. If someone is inputting those numbers somewhere, you can programmatically store those numbers, but the basic answer to your question is no.

Comment: I want to mathematically solve this problem. :( .. Is it possible to to find if i use any key to get upto all those value?

Comment: I am not sure why I got downvoted and then that person didn't offer an explanation...but, there is no way to solve this problem. Your equation would be a + b + c + d + e = 266. You have 5 unknowns that you have no way of calculating.